# How to set a custom field in a Django session model?

Tags: python, django, session

I have extended the session in Django per [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#example). In short, I have added a field named `account_id` to hold the user id of the user which the session belongs to.

Everything works fine, except the custom field `account_id` I have added is not being set on login. To do so:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from MyApp.models import CustomSession

def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        try:
            auth.login(request, user)
            session_key = request.session.session_key
            # CODE HERE
            if session_key is not None:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'Success'}))
            else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'Fail'}))
```

I have tried putting the following to `CODE HERE`. However, none of them worked:

1. `request.session.model.account_id = user.id`
2. ```
   session = CustomSession.objects.get(pk=session_key)
   session.account_id = user.id
   session.modified = True
   ```
3. `request.session.account_id = user.id`
4. `request.session[account_id] = user.id`

In each of these attempts, `account_id` is `NULL` in the data base.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do this? In propably 99.9% of the cases  it's not nessecary to connect a session with a user this way.

Comment: @trixn I am trying to easily obtain the list of online users.

Comment: Exactly how will this help you do that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I log out the users when they disconnect (users connect using WebSockets, so I can tell if they are connected or not). Hence, at any given time, the session table will tell me the list of online users.

Comment: I do not know where I have to place my code after extending the Django's Session class. The documentation contains code, but it doesn't contains the location tobe placed. Can anyone guide in adding additional field to the Database?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give a custom name or create a custom field in the session table, you can follow the following step.

Define a custom session backend:

```
my_project
    my_project/
        settings.py
        session_backend.py
        ...
    user/
        models.py
        ...
```

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
import user


class SessionStore(DBStore):

    @classmethod
    def get_model_class(cls):
        return user.models.MySession

    def create_model_instance(self, data):
        """
        overriding the function to save the changes to db using `session["user_id"] = user.id` .
        This will create the model instance with the custom field values. 
        When you add more field to the custom session model you have to update the function 
        to handle those fields as well.
        """
        obj = super().create_model_instance(data)
        try:
            user_id = data.get('user_id')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            user_id = None

        obj.user_id = user_id
        return obj
```

then in `settings.py` import your custom class

```py
SESSION_ENGINE = "my_project.session_backend"
```

Define the custom model in `models.py` in the app say `user`

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session


class MySession(Session):
    # you can also add custom field if required like this user column which can be the FK to the user table 
    user = models.ForeignKey('user', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    class Meta:
        app_label = "user"
        db_table = "my_session"
```

now run the following commands for migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Done :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, except I also had to place the session model in session_backend.py  because of recursive import

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that CustomSession is a model; you need to save the instance, not set "modified" on it as you do in version 2.

```
session = CustomSession.objects.get(pk=session_key)
session.account_id = user.id
session.save()
```

Comment: No luck. This didn't work either. The `account_id` is still `NULL`.

Comment: My guess is that Django is somehow re-saving the session upon exiting the `login` method, however with omitting the `account_id`.